# Leyenda y color en D3.js

Tags: d3.js

Buenso dias, estoy usando la libreria D3.js para dibujar un agrafico de sectores desde un arraylist de objetos.

Lo dibuja bien, pero me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera de que la leyenda se escriba por la parte de fuera, en vez de dentro del circulo

[image: Este es el grafico que dibujo]

```
         svg
      .selectAll('mySlices')
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.key})
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcGenerator.centroid(d) + ")";  })
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", 17)
```

y habria alguna manera de que me pinte diferentes colores aleatoriamente dependiendo de los valores que hay en el arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

Incrementa el valor de `arcGenerator.centroid(d)` o puedes declarar sus prodiedades:

```
const arcGenerator = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(200)  // <--- depende del radio del pie
    .outerRadius(400); // <--- depende del radio del pie
```